# Running a UIAlertController after func viewDidLoad() in a UIViewContriller Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I need to present an alert immediately after loading a view. This code is ignored. How can I get this alert to be presented?

```
class TrailerViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if gConnected == false{
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wifi Not Connected", message: "The Wifi is not connected to the Trailer Expert.", preferredStyle: .alert)

      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Connect", style: .default, handler: connectWifi()))
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ignore", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

      self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }
```

Comment: There's no point trying to display an alert from a view controller before the view controller is being displayed. Put the code in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Of course! This is what happens when one is a newbee. I didn't even know there was a viewDidAppear() function. Thanks Maddy.